# Verify user identity on Active Directory in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory, asp.net-identity

I have developed a web ASP.NET application, using ASP.NET identity 2.1.

Users must provide a username (email) and a password to log in, and they are stored, as usual in the local database of the application.

Now the company has implemented **Active Directory on Azure**, and they want that the users **authenticate** their self using the **credentials** of Active Directory on Azure to get access to the application.

The application users have to access is not on Azure, but on a **local server**, and all the resources needed by the application are on that server, only users identities are on Azure.

So what the step I need to do is:

1. Verify that the username exists in the local database. (maybe this step can be done after a positive authentication - step3)
2. Send a request to Azure that should verify the credentials of the user.
3. Get a response from Azure about the authentication...

ASP.NET Identity then should issue all the client cookies to grant and keep access to the application for the user.

I've seen that sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs but it seems that they need to **register** the app on Azure to make it works.

I need only to verify user identity and not his/her role, app authorization, permission, etc... because all this information is stored in the local database, including the user email.

Maybe the **WSFederation** is the one I have to use? **It's possible to implement the authentication without affecting the existing access authorization and permission managed by the ASP.NET Identity 2 in place?**

(Sorry but I've never implemented AAD authentication)

Comment: You have to register the app so the AAD knows that that app is allowed to query the AAD. If that would not be necessary we would have a security issue. Am I correct to use you only want to check whether the given username is present in the AAD?

Comment: @PeterBons Ok fine with the registration, you're right. Regarding authentication, the password is only stored in AAD so the user has to authenticate himself on AAD and the AAD must tell me if the user has a positive authentication (user-pass matches) so I can let him enter into the web application, and I need to know who is him, its username, in order to get his role and permissions from the local DB.

Comment: You'll need to authenticate the user with OpenID Connect, and after auth you'll get a signed token that contains their username.